# Using non-static IP computer as a Proxy server

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, remote-access, dynamic-dns

I have a Windows 7 computer connected to a Verizon T1114 router. This router allows me to get a new IP address at will simply by logging into the router and rebooting it, since this router is connected with a SIM card and has a data plan. The issue I'm trying to solve is being able to use this computer as a Proxy server for other computers. I tried setting up NO-IP.com dynamic DNS on the machine, but the problem I'm facing is that because I'm not using a static IP, I cannot access the computer from the outside internet(according to Verizon). I tried putting the computer's IP address in the router's DMZ, and tried to forward ports as well, but when I try to ping the public IP address, I get request timed out.

The goal is to be able to have 1 computer able to get a fresh IP address at will, and have many other computers able to use that machine's IP as a proxy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confusing the internal IP address of the computer (which probably starts 192.168 or 10. and is only visible on your LAN) with an external IP address which is visible from outside your LAN.

On the router you should be able to fix the internal IP address of the PC by binding it to the MAC address ( static DHCP assignment).  You then use this IP as the IP address of the proxy.

Part of your problem is something called hairpin NAT. This occurs when your internal computers try and speak to a server on your LAN using the external rather then internal address - but this is not possible because of a limitation of the NAT implementation. The workaround is to use the internal IP address - which sometimes requires hacks to the hosts file or running split DNS if you need to access it based on domain rather then IP.

Comment: I know the difference between LAN(internal) and public(external) IP addresses. I am trying to access the computer from another computer outside of the network. I have done this many times before on other routers with no problem, but with this router, because it does not use static IP, Verizon does not allow external access(according to Verizon).

Comment: In that case, listen to verizon - they are blocking incoming ports (and probably doing Carrier Grade NAT as well). If you want to bypass this, set up a VPN outside your Network and initiate a connection out to it. It will be fairly hard to control what goes via the VPN vs 4g though.